# which character encoding should i choose for my website? and how do i decide it?

Tags: html, utf-8

why is it important to declare character encoding in an HTML page and how do I decide that which type of character encoding should I choose for my website?

I used to simply use UTF-8 for all html pages. But is there any specific reason why I should use it?

Comment: Character encoding is one of the ignored arts - Something which every developer should know about but shouldn't have to. Now to answer the question: If you don't specify anything, then some default encoding will be chosen. On a typical system there are at least three sources for this default: OS, Java VM default if you use Java, web server config. They have difference precedence, any of them can change without prior notice and changes don't have an immediate effect for English developers, so problems in this area tend to ...

Comment: ... look random. On top of this, the encoding plays a role when you load files from hard disk (like serving static HTML), different pages of the same web site can have different encodings, some browsers don't support all encodings and finally some fonts don't have all the glyphs. It's a huge, ugly mess. My recommendation for people who don't want to spend a week or two learning all the details: Whenever you can set an encoding, do so. **Always use `UTF-8`.** Never use or rely on defaults. That way, at least half of your problem space disappears. ...

Comment: There was little you can do about client fonts; if you want to be safe(r) here as well, use web fonts or only the [safe set](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/the-myth-of-web-safe-fonts/) or aliases like `serif` which allow a browser to select a good font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use UTF-8:

- it supports everything (i.e. all languages and all symbols)
- it is supported be everything (all programming languages, frameworks, databases, you name it)
- it is the dominant encoding on the Web these days: http://googleblog.blogspot.ca/2012/02/unicode-over-60-percent-of-web.html

Any other encoding is asking for trouble.

You should specify encoding as UTF-8 because some pieces of software may default to ISO-8859-1 if not instructed not to.

Answer (score 0):

This is important because of HTML page can contain different languages. UTF-8 is multilingual encoding. But if your pages do not contain non-english characters, encoding is not important because all code pages have these english characters on the same position.